# Translation of "It doesn't have to ..."

Tags: traduction, verbes

The sentence "You don't have to go" is usually translated as

> Tu n'es pas obligé(e) d'y aller.

and **not**

> Tu ne dois pas y aller.

because the latter will be understood as "You mustn't go", which is very different.

What about

> A: I still have a page to write. I won't be able to finish it in time.
>
> B: Just write what you can. **It doesn't have to** be perfect.

How can we translate "doesn't have to" here?

> A: J'ai encore une page à écrire. Je ne pourrai pas la finir à temps.
>
> B: Écris simplement ce que tu peux. _____ être parfait.

Is it "Ce n'est pas obligé d'être parfait"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural in my opinion, would be:

> A: J'ai encore une page à écrire. Je ne pourrai pas la finir à temps.
>
> B: Écris simplement ce que tu peux. Ça n'a pas besoin d'être parfait.

I think that:

> Ce n'est pas obligé d'être parfait.

does not sound too good. I can't decide whether it's just uncommon or really incorrect, but I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

*Ça n'a pas besoin d'être parfait*